# is there performance difference in using model name istead of object in ForeignKey?

Tags: django, performance, foreign-keys, relational-database, django-database

Well [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) do not say anything about performance or particular situations when to use model name

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    related_model = ForeignKey('RelatedModel')
```

or the class itself

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    related_model = ForeignKey(RelatedModel)
```

in my experience is much better to use the model name to avoid import loops but does it have any particular impact on app's live peformance or just server startup takes longer? Can't really think of a test that would reliably check the performance thus the quetion
PS I know the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540654/difference-between-using-name-of-model-and-model-for-foreignkey) was asked but it says nothing about real performance.

Comment: Not significantly no. Django will check for each `ForeignKey` if it is a string, and then replace it by the model instance. But these are just dictionary lookups.

Comment: Thans for the answer its enough for me but maybe you will elaborate a bit and add it as an answer so others will see there is a correct answer to this question